# react-materialize $(...).tabs is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, materialize

Can't call `.tabs()` function from materialize, everything looks imported and in the right order, materializecss then jQuery then materialize.js. jQuery functions work fine, materialize - don't

> $(...).tabs is not a function

The problem should be somewhere in import but I can't get what's wrong.

index.html

```
 <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Import materialize.css -->
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.0/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet" >
    <title>Title</title>
  </head>
  <body>  

    <div id="root"></div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

  </body>
```

Component where I'm calling from

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import {Tab,Tabs} from 'react-materialize'
export default class Tab1 extends Component{

  next(){
    let $ = require('jquery');

    $('ul.tabs').tabs('select_tab','tab_01');
    // alert();
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div className="swipeTab" >
        <a onClick={()=> this.next()} className="waves-effect btn onasTabTrigger hoverable">Button</a>
      </div>

    );
  }
}
```

This Tab1 component is simply placed as a content of the tab in the parent

```
<Tabs className='tabs z-depth-1' tabOptions={{swipeable: true }} onChange={() => console.log(this)}>
  <Tab title="tab1" active >
    <Tab1 />
  </Tab>
  <Tab title="tab2" >
    <Tab2/>
  </Tab>
</Tabs>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put tab initialisation in `componentDidMount`.

Remove initialisation from `click` event on `next` call.

```
//onClick={()=> this.next()} remove it
```

**component :**

```
let $ = require('jquery');

export default class Tab1 extends Component{


        componentDidMount(){            
            //initialisation goes here.
          $('ul.tabs').tabs('select_tab','tab_01');
        }

        render(){  
            return(
              <div className="swipeTab" >                   
                     <a className="waves-effect btn onasTabTrigger hoverable">Button</a>  
                </div>
            );
        }
    }
```

Comment: thats not for initialization, this function should change active slide to the second one on 'a' click, which is a material styled button. Anyway, running function in Componentdidmount still gives same error